# How do I redirect to an external url and then redirect back to my python script using Flask

Tags: python, redirect, flask, imgur

I am trying to use IMGUR API using Flask. The problem is I am not able to find a way to get the data from the URL when the app redirects back to my script.

For example:

1. My script creates the auth url for IMGUR
2. Goes to that URL
3. Logins to IMGUR manually and then the API redirects back to my script
4. The url parameters are what I want, but I am not able to find a way to get the details from the URL.

Here is my code:

```
@imgurupload.route('/')
def routine():
    client = ImgurClient('REDACTED-CODE', 'REDACTED-CODE-REDACTED-CODE')
    authorization_url = client.get_auth_url('token')
    return redirect(authorization_url)
@imgurupload.route('/after')
def after_redirect():
    with app.test_request_context():
        print url_for('after_redirect')
    access_token = request.args.get('access_token')
    refresh_token = request.args.get('refresh_token')
    return access_token
if __name__ == '__main__':
    imgurupload.run()
```

Comment: Did you just post real Imgur tokens to Stack Overflow? You should invalidate them and generate new ones right now.

Comment: Imgur [uses OAuth 2.0](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2). Instead of trying to roll your own support it is probably a good idea to use an existing OAuth library.

Comment: It looks like you're using https://api.imgur.com/oauth2 ?

Comment: Yes I am using that. But the problem is returning to the script where I can parse the parameters from the URL!